# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime couldn't store in data column in c#.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, datatable, user-defined-types

I have defined a datatable in formload in c#.net as below

```
    DataTable dtreadd = new DataTable();
    dtreadd.Columns.Add("IDP");
    dtreadd.Columns.Add("date",typeof(DateTime));
    dtreadd.Columns.Add("day");
    dtreadd.Columns.Add("nobatkari");
    dtreadd.Columns.Add("code");
```

So I read some string from a file into this datatable

```
 void ReadToTable()
    {
        try
        {
            dtreadd.Clear();
            if (dir.Trim() != "")
            {
                c = 0;

                dtreadd.Clear();
                ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
                PersianCalendar persCal = new PersianCalendar();
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(DBsetting.Connstring);
                sqlconn.Open();
                foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(dir.Trim()))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim()))
                    {
                        c++;
                        l = line.Trim().Split('\t');
                        l[0] = l[0].Trim();
                        l[1] = l[1].Trim();
                        l[2] = l[2].Trim();
                        l[3] = l[3].Trim();
                        if (arrIDP.Contains(l[0]))
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(l[0]) && l[3] == "1" || l[3] == "0" || l[3] == "7")
                            {
                                dtreadd.Rows.Add(l[0], l[1], GetDayOfWeek(GetPerDate(l[1])), "",l[3]);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

                using (sqlconn)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertTaradodReadd", sqlconn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlParameter dtparam =cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INFO_ARRAY", dtreadd);
                    dtparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    RefGrid();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {     
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);   
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

Records in file is Below

```
  1)  1 2017-04-09 15:33:39 1   0   1   0        
  2)  1 2017-07-31 08:08:24 1   0   1   0
  3)  4 2017-07-31 08:13:39 1   0   1   0
  4) 2  2017-07-31 08:18:54 1   0   1   0
  5)  4 2017-07-31 13:10:10 1   0   1   0
  6) 2  2017-07-31 14:08:11 1   0   1   0
  7) 1  2017-07-31 17:03:36 1   0   1   0
```

For first record it works ok but for second one  2)  1  2017-07-31 08:08:24 1   0   1   0 it raises an error 
error is 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime couldn't store <    2017-07-31 08:08:24> in data column expected type is Datatime.'
when I see the records I notice that evry things are ok and records are fine but I dont know why there is an error for only this record

@INFO_ARRAY is defined below in sqlserver

```
USE [HoghooghDastmozd]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedTableType [dbo].[ReadArrayyy]    Script Date: 01/08/1396 12:26:34 ب.ظ ******/
DROP TYPE [dbo].[ReadArrayyy]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedTableType [dbo].[ReadArrayyy]    Script Date: 01/08/1396 12:26:34 ب.ظ ******/
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ReadArrayyy] AS TABLE(
    [IDP] [int] NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL,
    [day] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [nobatkari] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [code] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
GO


DateTime GetPerDate(string dt1)
{
    string[] a = dt1.Split(' ');
    string[] ss = a[0].Split('/','-');
    string[] hh = a[1].Split(':');
    string year = ss[2];
    string month = ss[1];
    string day = ss[0];
    string hour = hh[0];
    string min = hh[1];
    string sec = hh[2];
    DateTime dd = new DateTime(int.Parse(year), int.Parse(month), int.Parse(day), int.Parse(hour), int.Parse(min), int.Parse(sec), new PersianCalendar());

    return dd;//string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5}", year, month, day, hour, min, sec);
}
```

Comment: Presumably it's `GetPerDate` that's throwing an exception, and you haven't shown us that.

Comment: What's `InsertTaradodReadd` look like?

Comment: I guess the month and day are recognized reversely. 31 is not a valid month number.

Comment: you have to do some thing like this ........                                                       DateTime.ParseExact(l[1], "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @ Jon Skeet : I posted GetPerDate() function Please check